# VS Code, LaTeX Workshop: Viewer jumps to the first page when saving

Tags: compiling, vscode, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code with the LaTeX Workshop extension on Ubuntu 18.04. I enabled the "Build on save" option, with the browser as the PDF viewer. It has always worked fine. However, it suddenly has picked up a mildly annoying behavior: when I save any changes to the .tex document, the viewer jumps to the front page of the PDF, so that I have to scroll down to see the changes that I have just made.

Has anyone encountered the same behavior? Do you have any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: A coauthor had that problem.  I think it is to do with a setting that automatically makes the input move with the location of the output.  If you turn that feature off then the behavior will stop.

Comment: Thank you both! After rebooting, the behavior stopped.

Answer (score 1):

Same error for me but did not go away by rebooting or even switching computers.  However, I was working on a large file with many graphics and given @JPi hint looked at the options for refreshing.

- click on Extensions in VS code, scroll till you find LaTeX workshop,
- select the gears on the upper right for settings.
- scroll through the setting to find this part and change the number to a larger one.
  [image]
  Default was 250 milliseconds.  Increasing that number not only fixed the page reset problem but also reduced the flickering I was getting as the build would make several passes.  Maybe this helps someone with a related issued.